# 4 bit full subtraction with a 1 bit full subtractor

Tags: verilog, subtraction

I'm trying to us a 1 bit full subtractor by a 4 bit module as so - I'm a little stuck on where to go next, I'm not sure what's happening under the hood - I thought maybe I could us fullsub in a loop of sub4 and iterate over each of the bits and update the in vs out, but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
module fullSub(x, y, b_in, diff, b_out);
  input x, y, b_in;
  output diff, b_out;
  assign diff=(x^y)^b_in;
  assign b_out = (~(x^y)&b_in) | ((~x)&y);
endmodule

module sub4(x, y, b_in, diff, b_out);
  input [3:0] x, y;
  input b_in; 
  output [3:0] diff;
  output b_out;

  fullSub init[3:0](x, y, b_in, diff, b_out);
  assign b_in = b_out;

endmodule
```

Comment: Have a look at "generate for" loops that can be used to instantiate multiple modules - in this case, four chained full subtractors.

Comment: thank you! as a secondary question - should I create a half-subber, or is it ok to just re-use the fullSub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following and it worked well - thanks.

```
wire [3:0] borrow
genvar i;
generate
for(i=3; i>=0; i=i-1)
  begin: description
    if(i===0)
      fullSub s(x[i], y[i], b_in, diff[i], borrow[i]);
    else
      fullSub s(x[i], y[i], borrow[i-1], diff[i], borrow[i]);
  end
  assign b_out = borrow[3];
endgenerate
```